# Do quantum fields with energy stored in it usually exert pressure?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, pressure, field-theory

There are types of quantum fields in the universe like spinor, vector, tensor, scalar fields.

**Do these fields with energy stored in it (as energy density) usually exert pressure, or be pressureless?**

Since pressure can be positive or negative. Is a field more likely to exert positive pressure than be pressureless, and more likely to exert negative pressure than be pressureless?

Comment: I don't know how you "store energy" in a quantum field, given that it has no fixed values to begin with. Of course particles as "excitations of a quantum field" (if you insist on using that terribly unenlightening phrase) will exert pressure as usual.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I’ve been reading about inflation on the internet. And I learned that inflation can be modeled from  a scalar, spinor, vector, tensor field. So I assume that these quantum fields can store energy which decay after inflation ended.